# get instance in BroadCastReceiver class for receive sms in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to get instance from textview in broad cast receiver in android for received sms.
I want to display sms in textview and use from "textview.settext("SmsContentEtc")" but beacuse I coudent on creat method in class, I coudent get instance from textview !!!!

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private TextView txtshow;
     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {       
            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                         
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";  `enter code here`
                }
                //---display the new SMS message---
               //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtshow.setText("smsContentEtc");
            }                         
        }
    }
```

Comment: so whats your question and what have you tried so far??

Comment: if you paste your code here we can help you..

Answer (score 0):

Put the text in an intent and send that intent to your activity.

1. If activity is not running then it will be created and you need to get the text from intent and show it in a text view.
2. If activity is already running then based upon activity's launch mode activity will get the new intent or new instance of activity will be invoked with the intent.